# The statement does not return a result set SQL Server exception

Tags: java, sql-server, stored-procedures, jdbc

I have a stored procedure "executeStoredProc" which executes another stored procedure "SP1". So there is a temp table that is being created within the "executeStoredProc" and then the data of SP1 is fed to a temp table and then the resultset is retrieved. But when I execute the stored procedure from the SQL server Management Studio I get the resultset but when i use the Prepared statement to execute the "executeStoredProc" from jdbc I do not get the resultset.

So here the query part is a class that gives me all the parameters that I can pass to "executeStoredProc". When I execute this procedure I get an error that the statement does not return the resultset.

I am using JDBC to run the procedure.

```
QueryPart queryPart = new QueryPart(query);


    String storedProcedureName = queryPart.getFrom();
                String groupByParameters = queryPart.getGroup();
                String orderByParameters = queryPart.getOrder();
                String nullString = null;
                String whereClauseParameters = null;
                if(queryPart.getWhere()!=null){
                    whereClauseParameters = queryPart.getWhere();
                }else{
                    whereClauseParameters = nullString;
                }
                String parametersOfSP = parameter;

                String selectParameterList = null;
                String aliasParameterList = null;
                CallableStatement callableStatement = null;
                PreparedStatement pStatement = null;
                StringBuffer storedProcedureExecutionStatement  = new StringBuffer();
    StringBuffer parameters = new StringBuffer();
                if(parametersOfSP !=null){
                    String[] parameterStringArray = parametersOfSP.split(",");
                    for(int i=0;i<parameterStringArray.length;i++){
                        if(parameterStringArray[i].contains("=")){
                            parameters.append(parameterStringArray[i].split("=")[1]+",");
                        }else{
                            parameters.append(parameterStringArray[i]+",");
                        }
                    }
                }
                if (parameters.toString().endsWith(",")) {
                    parametersOfSP = parameters.toString().substring(0, parameters.length()-1);
                }else{
                    parametersOfSP = nullString;
                }

                StringBuffer selectedParameter = new StringBuffer();
                StringBuffer aliasParameter = new StringBuffer();
                String selectParameterStringStatement = query.split("From")[0].split("Select")[1];
                String[] selectParams = selectParameterStringStatement.split(",");

                for(int i=0;i<selectParams.length;i++){
                    selectedParameter.append(selectParams[i].split("AS")[0]+",");
                    aliasParameter.append(selectParams[i].split("AS")[1]+",");
                }

                if (selectedParameter.toString().endsWith(",")) {
                    selectParameterList = selectedParameter.toString().substring(0, selectedParameter.length()-1);
                }
                if (aliasParameter.toString().endsWith(",")) {
                    aliasParameterList = aliasParameter.toString().substring(0, aliasParameter.length()-1);
                }
    storedProcedureExecutionStatement.append("EXEC "+ ApplicationProperties.getValue("app.aspose.wrapperStoredProcName") 
                            +" @pi_sp_name ='"+ storedProcedureName +"',@pi_sp_params ='"+parametersOfSP+"'");
                    storedProcedureExecutionStatement.append(",@pi_col_names = '"+ selectParameterList+"'");
                    storedProcedureExecutionStatement.append(",@pi_col_aliases = '"+ aliasParameterList+"'");
                    if(whereClauseParameters!=null){
                        storedProcedureExecutionStatement.append(",@pi_where_cls = '"+whereClauseParameters+"'");
                    }else{
                        storedProcedureExecutionStatement.append(",@pi_where_cls = "+nullString);
                    }
                    if(groupByParameters!=null){
                        storedProcedureExecutionStatement.append(",@pi_group_by_cls = '"+groupByParameters+"'");
                    }else{
                        storedProcedureExecutionStatement.append(",@pi_group_by_cls = "+nullString);
                    }
                    if(orderByParameters!=null){
                        storedProcedureExecutionStatement.append(",@pi_order_by_cls = '"+orderByParameters+"'");
                    }else{
                        storedProcedureExecutionStatement.append(",@pi_order_by_cls = "+nullString);
                    }
                    pStatement = conn.prepareStatement(storedProcedureExecutionStatement.toString());
                    //rset = (ResultSet)
                    pStatement.execute();
                    crs = new CachedRowSetImpl();
                    crs.populate(rset);
```

Comment: Please reduce the code to basic JDBC without the string manipulation you are currently doing, that would make it a lot easier to understand. I also see funky stuff at the end: you use `execute()`, and then populate a `CachedRowSet` with a `ResultSet` that doesn't seem to be defined anywhere. However, the most likely cause is execution of a stored procedure that produces result counts before the result set. You might want to try adding `SET NOCOUNT ON` at the start of your stored procedure.

Comment: Well I have added SET NOCOUNT ON at the beginning of the SP but that does not seem to add any value.

Comment: Then please 1) reduce your code to the absolute minimum necessary to reproduces the error, and 2) post the code of the simplest stored procedure that reproduces the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use execute method of Statement to execute a given SQL statement, it might return multiple result sets and output parameters. In some situations, a single SQL statement may return multiple result sets and/or update counts. Normally you can ignore this unless you are

-executing a stored procedure that you know may return multiple results.

-dynamically executing an unknown SQL string.

The execute method excutes an SQL statement and returns a boolean value. When the value is true, the first result returned from the statements is a result set. When the value is false, the first result returned was an update count. You must then use the methods getResultSet or getUpdateCount to retrieve the result, and getMoreResults to move to any subsequent result(s).

When the result of a SQL statement is not a result set, the method getResultSet will return null. This can mean that the result is an update count or that there are no more results. The only way to find out what the null really means in this case is to call the method getUpdateCount, which will return an integer. This integer will be the number of rows affected by the calling statement or -1 to indicate either that the result is a result set or that there are no results. If the method getResultSet has already returned null, which means that the result is not a ResultSet object, then a return value of -1 has to mean that there are no more results.

If one has called the method getResultSet and processed the ResultSet object it returned, it is necessary to call the method getMoreResults to see if there is another result set or update count. If getMoreResults returns true, then one needs to again call getResultSet to actually retrieve the next result set. As already stated above, if getResultSet returns null, one has to call getUpdateCount to find out whether null means that the result is an update count or that there are no more results.

```
CallableStatement cs=null;
        ResultSet rs =null;
        try {
            Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlserver://<server_ip>;databaseName=<dbName>", "<userName>", "<Password>");
            cs = con.prepareCall("exec exampleProcedure");
            int resultNum = 0;
            while (true)
              {
                  boolean queryResult;
                  int rowsAffected;
                  if (1 == ++resultNum)
                  {
                      try
                      {
                          queryResult = cs.execute();
                          System.out.println("QueryResult:"+queryResult);
                      }
                      catch (SQLException e)
                      {
                          System.out.println("Result " + resultNum + " is an error: " + e.getMessage());
                          continue;
                      }
                  }
                  else
                  {
                      try
                      {
                          queryResult = cs.getMoreResults();
                          System.out.println("QueryResult:"+queryResult);
                      }
                      catch (SQLException e)
                      {                       
                          System.out.println("Result " + resultNum + " is an error: " + e.getMessage());
                          continue;
                      }
                  }
                  if (queryResult)
                  {
                      rs = cs.getResultSet();
                      System.out.println("Result " + resultNum + " is a ResultSet: " + rs);
                      //rs.close();
                  }
                  else
                  {
                      rowsAffected = cs.getUpdateCount();
                      System.out.println("rowsAffected:"+rowsAffected);
                      if (-1 == rowsAffected)
                      {
                          --resultNum;
                          break;
                      }
                      System.out.println("Result " + resultNum + " is an update count: " + rowsAffected);
                  }
              }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```